# Odoo 12 AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ids'

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I am trying to get mail when a new record is created and modified for a field in CRM Module so I have defined these functions

in py:

```
@api.multi
def write (self, vals):
    if 'lead_status' in vals and self.ids:
        for rec in self:
            template = self.env.ref ('crm_extended.crm_lead_mail_template')
            template.send_mail (rec.id, force_send = True)          
    return super (crm_extended, self) .write (vals)

@api.multi
def create (self, vals):
    if 'lead_status' in vals and self.ids:
        for rec in self:
            template = self.env.ref ('crm_extended.create_crm_lead_mail_template')
            template.send_mail (rec.id, force_send = True)          

    return super (crm_extended, self) .write (vals)
```

when the change the state or give save, odoo popping me an error as below

Error:

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception

return super (JsonRequest, self) ._ handle_exception (exception)

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception

raise pycompat.reraise (type (exception), exception, sys.exc_info () [2])

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise

raise value

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch

result = self._call_function (** self.params)

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function

return checked_call (self.db, * args, ** kwargs)

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 98, in wrapper

return f (dbname, * args, ** kwargs)

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call

result = self.endpoint (* a, ** kw)

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__

return self.method (* args, ** kw)

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap

response = f (* args, ** kw)

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 962, in call_kw

return self._call_kw (model, method, args, kwargs)

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in _call_kw

return call_kw (request.env [model], method, args, kwargs)

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/api.py", line 757, in call_kw

return _call_kw_model_create (method, model, args, kwargs)

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/api.py", line 737, in _call_kw_model_create

result = method (recs, * args, ** kwargs)

File "<decorator-gen-260>", line 2, in create

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/api.py", line 461, in _model_create_multi

return create (self, [arg])

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/addons/base_automation/models/base_automation.py", line 231, in create

action._process (action._filter_post (records))

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/addons/base_automation/models/base_automation.py", line 164, in _filter_post

return self._filter_post_export_domain (records) [0]

File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/addons/base_automation/models/base_automation.py", line 169, in _filter_post_export_domain

domain = [('id', 'in', records.ids)] + safe_eval (self.filter_domain, self._get_eval_context ())

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ids'
```

function:

```py
@api.multi
def create (self, vals):
    if 'lead_status' in vals and self.ids:
        for rec in self:
            template = self.env.ref ('crm_extended.create_crm_lead_mail_template')
            template.send_mail (rec.id, force_send = True)
    return super (crm_extended, self) .write (vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use `self` before calling `super` and you called the super write method instead of the `create` method.

Try to correct the `create` method inheritance:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(crm_extended, self).create(vals)
    if 'lead_status' in vals:
        template = self.env.ref('crm_extended.create_crm_lead_mail_template')
        for record in res:
            template.send_mail (record.id, force_send=True) 
    return res
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , iam getting mail for the modification but iam not getting while creating the record please tell me whats wrong

Comment: customer_name = fields.Many2one("res.partner","Account Name",track_visibility='onchange') ,     @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        rec = super(crm_extended, self).create(vals)
        if 'customer_name' in vals:
            template = self.env.ref('crm_extended.create_crm_lead_mail_template')
            for rec in self:
                template.send_mail (rec.id, force_send=True) 
        return rec

Comment: Odoo will try to send an email if `customer_name` is in `vals` (`lead_status` for the write method). The comma after the `customer_name` field declaration should be removed.

Comment: which one bro ?

Answer (score 0):

you can not write `@api.multi` above the create method.

you have to use `@api.model`.